# Hyperbolic functions both produce error and result already existant when inserted in preamble

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I'm trying to write hyperbolic functions like sech, csch, etc,

Since amsmath doesn't recognize them in the form `\sech`, `\csch`, ...

I wrote a preamble like `\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}` but I get this error:

`! LaTex Error: Command \tanh already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual.`

how should I write the hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: after this comment I worked it out: `tanh` and `coth` were already defined, `sech` and `csch` neededd to be defined in the preamble

Comment: Barbara Beeton already answered: The standard hyperbolic function macros are there, `\sech` etc are quite rare, in my point of view, so they weren't defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not all the hyperbolic functions are defined in `amsmath` (actually, in `amsopn.sty`).
only `\sinh`, `\cosh`, `\tanh` and `\coth` are defined there.

you can define the others exactly like you've shown for `\sech`, and can check in
`amsopn.sty` if you encounter any other conflicts.

`amsopn.sty` was never meant to be exhaustive.  it covers only the operator names
found most frequently in ams publications as of the time it was compiled.
there are surely many other possibilities.

Comment: after having read this answer first in the comments I worked it out: `tanh` and `coth` were already defined, `sech` and `csch` needed to be defined in the preamble. thanks